# Error when chain dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion and presentViewController:animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

When a modalView is presented, a network event generates a new modal view controller. what I'm doing is to chain the presentViewController:animated inside of dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion like this:

```
//    ModalViewController *vc = ...
    if (self.presentedViewController) {
        __weak MyViewController *me = self;
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                         completion:
         ^{
             // need a delay to call?
             dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [me presentViewController:vc
                                  animated:YES
                                completion:nil];
             });
         }];
    }else{        
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

It all goes well: the original modal viewcontroller dismissed, the network generated one presented, and user can dismiss it successfully. however, when trying to present a 3rd modalViewController, it failed with error:

```
2014-03-26 15:49:52.111 coshop[6046:60b] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <RootViewController: 0xa8b54a0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

I also tried this:

```
if (self.presentedViewController) {
    __weak MyViewController *me = self;
    [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                     completion:nil];

         // dismiss animation ends within 0.5.
         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [me presentViewController:vc
                              animated:YES
                            completion:nil];
         });

}else{        
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: Do you not want to present without animation while the current modal is still up, then bring the current modal down? Indeed, why so many modals??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? sounds like a lot of modal windows

Comment: yes, indeed lots of modal view. the first modal view is the user generated, the 2nd is network event generated, and the 3rd is again generated by user. the problem seems something missing so that when the 2nd is dismissed the system doesn't think so -- so that not able to present the 3rd.

Comment: @wangii no what is a brief description of what your app is trying to do / display. I understand how they are getting triggered. But having so many modal's sounds like a very bad design, forgetting the issue your having, you should try do it another way

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin agree. the modal view contains a webview lead to a ppc page, which is the only place to make money from. this page wants full attention from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the VC doesn't appear anymore in the simulator or your device, doesn't mean it's animation hasn't fully completed.

I suspect that your "3rd modalViewController" is not being presented *after* the second network generated view controller is dismissed. The reason it works in the first case is because you have it presenting in the dismissed vc's dismiss completion block.

If the 3rd is presented by a user action, you need to ensure that they can't perform that action before the other vc's dismissal or presentation has completed.

What you might want to do is set the user's action up in a block that you then pass as a parameter to the class that presents the next view controller, and execute the block from the presentation completion block.

Comment: added guards isBeingPresented & isBeingDismissed solved the problem. thanks!